# How to disable field on Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I create Repeater field table for Advanced Custom Field plugin, I set location show on User, but I want User **only views** not edit. and Admin will edit. So, how to disable field edit on User?

Comment: the question is off-topic as it is not  wordpress question. you better ask the plugin developer.

Comment: There's an official support topic here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/read-only-field-2/

Answer (score 2):

ACF has  some actions and filter, one of the actions you should check is [`acf/render_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-render_field/). It runs to render a field input. You can hook into this action and modify your input to be read-only or even completely replace the input with its value.

Another option is to set up location rule: `User role - is equal to - Administrator`. This will show the edit form to Administrators only. And then write some custom code to just show the fields values to non-administrator.